# selecting records according to created_at field in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 4 `radio buttons` that each of them correspond to a time period:

- last week
- last month
- last day

I want to select database records according these times.

For example when the user chooses *last month*, all records from last month till now should be displayed but my `created_at field` doesn't work.

What is your idea?

Comment: Please show the code you have so we have something to start from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Record` class I would create a query scope (http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes):

```
public function scopeCreatedLastXDays($query, $nb)
{
    return $query->where('created_at', '>=', new DateTime('-'.$nb.' days')); 
}
```

Then I would check for inputs:

```
if (Input::has('last_month'))
    $records = Record::createdLastXDays(30)->get();
if (Input::has('last_week'))
    $records = Record::createdLastXDays(7)->get();
```